# ACF to LUCEE conversion

Tags: lucee

ajax CFC with can’t be found in lucee

Message:

```
invalid component definition, can’t find component [mycomp]
Stacktrace :    The Error Occurred in<br>
/lucee/core/ajax/AjaxProxyHelper.cfc: line 26<br>
called from /AjaxProxy.cfc: line 73<br>
called from /AjaxProxy.cfc: line 45<br>
called from ..\..\daftarMohon.cfm: line 135

<cfajaxproxy cfc="mycomp" jsclassname="validation">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

I don't bother with cfc's any longer. I send $.ajax straight to a .cfm page and have the .cfm page do a SerializeJSON(qry).

I don't use the tag based syntax any longer. I use the cfscript syntax instead.

I don't use cfquery any longer. I use stored procedures instead.

I don't use $.ajax any longer. I use fetch instead.

Comment: ok i get ur point but my program use many cfc as to fetch data. is there any way to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

It might be just a mapping problem, does `<cfdump var=#createObject("component","mycomp")#>` show your component?

Comment: yes it show my component, 

VALIDAHLI 
Remote Function validAhli
source:F:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\ekpkp\permohonan\mycomp.cfc
arguments 
label name required type default hint
Myid true string null 
noAhli true string null 
return type string

Comment: seem it cannot find my cfc 'mycomp' file as i use this code 

"<cfajaxproxy cfc="mycomp" jsclassname="validation">"

Comment: sorry, turns out it's a known problem, there is a fix pending https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1494